# Inserting data in my DB but there is an exception thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this error when I try to insert data into database

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)**: *Incorrect syntax near 'Name'at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.*
>
> OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
> ds) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean asyncWrite) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1
> completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
> Boolean asyncWrite) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
> adduser.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ibtisam
> Tanveer\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\adduser.aspx.cs:line 53
> ClientConnectionId:df4aec92-1f96-4236-9bd7-f802a52b5213 Error
> Number:102,State:1,Class:15

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class adduser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DonorInformationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conec.Open();
            string checkuserCNIC = "select count(*) from Donor where CNIC='" + TextBoxCNIC.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuserCNIC,conec);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Already Exists");
            }

            conec.Close();
            
        }

    }
    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DonorInformationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conec.Open();
            string insertquerry = "insert into Donor(First Name, Last Name, Cell number, Email, CNIC, City, Address, Blood Group, Gender, Password) values (@firstname, @lastname, @cell, @email, @cnic, @city, @address, @blood, @sex, @password)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquerry, conec);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBoxFirst_Name.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBoxLast_Name.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", TextBoxPhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox_Email.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnic", TextBoxCNIC.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList_City.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", TextBox_Address.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blood", DropDownListBloodGroup.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", DropDownList_Gender.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxCNIC.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Donor Added Successfully");
            conec.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("There is some Errors Please Read------------------>" + ex.ToString());
        }

            
    }
    protected void DropDownList_Gender_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried yourself? Or is this going to be some challenge for us? Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your correction I will consider these things in my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this `First Name` like `[First Name]` and other columns too.

You should always use `[]` if you have space in column name. Also you should be avoiding space in column names.

So your code becomes

```
string insertquerry = "insert into Donor([First Name], [Last Name], 
    [Cell number], Email, CNIC, City, Address, Blood Group, Gender, 
    Password) values (@firstname, @lastname, @cell, @email, @cnic, @city, 
     @address, @blood, @sex, @password)";
```

Comment: Using the `[]` around your field names will also escape out fields that share their names with keywords in SQL. Ie: `Select ID, [From] from [Table]` (that's an example of extremely bad field name but it happens)

Comment: Thank you exception removed now